# Forth to the past - mergesort preps

Tags: algorithm, forth

Still oiling my Forth. Below are few essential algorithms for in-place merge. Please review.

Some introductory comments:

- `>swap<` is not a cute smiley. I am trying to tell that two pointers are going towards each other at each swap.
- `rdrop drop` looks hideously ugly. Any suggestions?
- `lower-bound` and `upper-bound` must be unified. How can I do that without `execute`?

```
: @swap ( a a -- )
    2dup @ >r @ ! r> !
;

: lower-bownd ( lo hi v -- lb )
    >r
    begin 2dup - cell > while
        2dup over - 2/ +
        dup @ r@ < if
            cell+ -rot then
        swap drop
    repeat
    rdrop drop

: upper-bound ( lo hi v -- ub )
    >r
    begin 2dup - cell > while
        2dup over - 2/ +
        dup @ r@ >= if
            cell+ -rot then
        swap drop
    repeat
    rdrop drop

: >swap< ( a0 a1 -- a1++ --a1 )
    cell - 2dup @swap swap cell+ swap
;

:reverse (lo hi -- )
    begin 2dup < while
        >swap<
    repeat
    drop
;

: reverse-until ( lo hi mi -- lo' hi' pp )
    >r
    begin 2dup r@ = swap r@ = or while
        >swap<
    repeat
    r>
    over = if
        over then
        dup else
;

: rotate ( lo mi hi -- pp )
    2dup reverse  rot
    2dup reverse -rot
    swap reverse-until
    >r reverse r>
;
```